# Sleeping go routine never wakes up/being blocked forever

Tags: go, goroutine

My problem can be summarized as the following snippet:

```
    package main

   import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
   )


func main() {

    done := make(chan int)
    done2 := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        for {
            fmt.Println("1")
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(1) * time.Second)
        }

        done <- 1
    }()



    go func() {
        for {
            fmt.Println("2")
        }
        done2 <- 1
    }()

    <- done
    <- done2

}
```

Where the go routine "1" never gets the chance to run again. After doing some research, it looks like it's because go routine "2" takes up all the CPU.

I had done something similar in java before, and thread "1" can always wake up approximately 1 sec later.

My question is how can I achieve the same behavior in go?(I'm transferring a socket program originally written in Java to Go)

I have also tried runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2), but didn't work

Comment: This is an example that illustrates my issue. As I mentioned, I'm rewriting a java socket-related program in go. The real groutines I have aren't just a few print statements and would be much too complex to post

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I mean is that if you use that code, the goroutine scheduler will properly schedule all your goroutines. If you add a 1 ms sleep in the loop of goroutine #2, you will get the same result.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean adding 1ms sleep to groutine 2?

Comment: goroutines are not threads. As of the current version, they are not preemptible. Tight loops like that will not let other goroutines run.

Comment: @user9607441 Yes, edited my previous comment.

Comment: @icza great! Just tried and it works! And easy enough for me to make changes!Thanks!!

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Btw, having a `fmt.Println()` in a loop does not prevent the goroutine scheduler to run other goroutines, as that involves IO operations. So in your example all your goroutines get scheduled, but your example code have endless loops and they never end.

Comment: Note that a "socket" program in Go should never have any code like this anyway, and if the goroutines need to be coordinated, `time.Sleep` is never the answer. It would be better to show what the actual problem is.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for your reply! The original Java program has 2 threads: Thread 1 sends a request message and wait 1 sec(i.e. time.sleep), and then check the reply in "queue"(see thread 2); Thread 2 is an infinite loop that listen for the reply and store the message into the "queue". Because the server would send other information periodically, the thread 2 would need to be an infinite loop. Hope this is clear -- and my current go program would stuck in that wait after sending

Comment: @user9607441: network operations are blocking, so I don't see any reason there needs to be any sleep at all (other than maybe spacing between messages). The scenario you describe is very different from what you wrote above. The infinite loop itself is not a problem, every network server has a loop by definition; the problem is that while network operations only run when there is data, your Println continues immediately.

Comment: In general, if you're having problems with some code, post *that* code, not a vaguely-similar example. This example is so contrived that it's guaranteed to be irrelevant to any issue you're having with socket programming in Go.

Answer (score -1):

Go routines to someone new to Go can have a number of surprising side effects. One of the more important of these is the problems of empty infinite loops.

The way that the Go scheduler works, every function call should get a preemption point placed in the beginning of the call. This should be happening with your `fmt.Println("2")` call, meaning that every time a print is called, the scheduler in the background has the ability to move around what routines are running at any given time, increase memory for a goroutine, etc.

Under normal circumstances, even if it is not ideally written code, this should be enough. Given that you have stated in the comments that this is not the actual code that you are working with, its not really possible to answer why your other code might not be working.

If you are interested in learning more about how the go scheduler works, I would recommend [this](https://medium.com/a-journey-with-go/go-goroutine-and-preemption-d6bc2aa2f4b7) article which goes over preemption, and [these](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2018/08/scheduling-in-go-part1.html) articles which covers the scheduler at a lower level.

I would also recommend taking a look through the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) site. While some of the concepts are rather basic, there are some very complex things that you can do if you are aware of all the tools in your toolbox. I would specifically recommend the [concurrency section](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1), and the [select statement](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5), which might be able to help you refactor your program easier, and in a manner more fitting to go.